# Get Resources with string

Tags: c#

I have a lot of txt files in Resources folder. One of them is corner.txt. I can access this file via this code snippet:

```
Properties.Resources.corner
```

I keep file names in string variables. For example:

```
string fileName = "corner.txt";
```

**I want to access this file via:**

```
Properties.Resources.fileName
```

Is this possible? How can I access?

Comment: It's utterly unclear what you're asking. Where is this `fileName`? Is it a generated asset? Is it a local variable you've declared in some utterly disassociated class? What?

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3314213/2524304

Comment: Setting text in bold is not clearing up what you're asking for. Is fileName a full path or only the file name? Or is it a class that you want to access?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to read embedded resource text file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3314140/how-to-read-embedded-resource-text-file)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17837224/1954447

Answer (score 80, accepted):

I solved the problem this code snippet:

```
string st = Properties.Resources.ResourceManager.GetString(tableName);
```

So, I don't use the filename, I use the txt file's string. This is useful for me.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: I didnt get it. Can you give some more detail, please

Comment: He wanted to access resources via the string resource entry name and not by the intellisense properties.

Comment: I had to find an image in the resources, so I used:
var image = Properties.Resources.ResourceManager.GetObject(resourceName);

Answer (score 11):

You can use [Reflection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173183%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) like that:

```
var type = typeof(Properties.Resources);
var property = type.GetProperty(fileName, BindingFlags.Static| BindingFlags.NonPublic|BindingFlags.Public);
var value = property.GetValue(null, null);
```

or use the `ResourceManager` like that:

```
value = Properties.Resources.ResourceManager.GetObject(fileName, Properties.Resources.Culture);
```