# How to convert a string to code? (C#)

Tags: c#, string, picturebox

Is it possible to convert a string to code? 
For example, instead of:

```
string foo = "bar";
...
switch(foo){
case "bar":
    pictureBox.Image = Project.Properties.Resources.bar;
    break;
...
}
```

Is there a way to simply:

```
string foo = "bar"
pictureBox.Image = Project.Properties.Resources.<foo string goes in here>;
```

I hope this example makes sense.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17828774/get-resources-with-string

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get property value from string using reflection in C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1196991/get-property-value-from-string-using-reflection-in-c-sharp)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you are trying to do is called Reflection in C#. You can find a post in StackOverflow with code samples for it: [Get property value from string using reflection in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1196991/get-property-value-from-string-using-reflection-in-c-sharp)

EDIT: Here is the example

```
     string foo = "bar";
     var resources = Project.Properties.Resources;
     object o = resources.GetType().GetProperty(foo).GetValue(resources, null);
     if (o is System.Drawing.Image) {
            pictureBox.Image = (System.Drawing.Image) o;
     }
```

Comment: it is called reflection, not only in c# ... ;)

Comment: In the above example, would you be able to provide an example?