# Call Resource with string variable

Tags: c#, .net

I would like to use the resources in my solution by passing a string variable to Properties.Resources:

```
string[] documents = new string[] { "one", "two", "three"};
foreach (var document in documents)
{
   extractFile(String.Format(@"C:\temp\{0}.doc",document), properties.Resources.document);
}

private void extractFile (string destinationFile, byte[] sourceFile)
{
   File.WriteAllBytes(destinationFile, sourceFile);
}
```

But i cannot use the string "document" for properties.Resources like this.

('Resources' does not contain a definition for 'document')

How can I make this work?

Comment: This is not how `foreach` works.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get Resources with string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17828774/get-resources-with-string)

Comment: @ASh: Its not a duplicate, a read the other one. The problem in the other one is they want to retrieve the recources name i guess... ?

Comment: @Soner Gönöl: Ok, why not? (but this isnt the issue)

Comment: Nomistake, it does appear to be a duplicate, that is exactly what you're trying to do

Comment: @Sayse: I have read it before, but it didnt help me. But i'm willing to read it again.

Comment: The op in that question wasn't trying to get the name of the resource but their resource was of type `String`. Perhaps your's isn't. If so, there are other [methods in ResourceManager](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.resources.resourcemanager%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) that will work

Comment: Maybe it wasnt so clear but my resources are byte[] ... and they have a name.
I want to call them by the name bij passing the string to Properties.Resources...

Comment: It looks like you expect `properties.Resources.document` to be 'translated' to `properties.Resources.one`, `properties.Resources.two`, and so on. That's not how it works in C#. You could use reflection for this, but `ResourceManager` already provides methods that accept a string and return the object or stream you're looking for, so just use those, as Sayse already mentioned.

Comment: @PieterWitvoet Yes, you got it. I know this isnt working like this in c#, therefore this question...

Comment: I'll have a look at the ResourceManager... But its a new one for me

Comment: it may be of further help if you can show how properties.Resources.document is being used in `extractFile` method. Perhaps you just need to pass the resource class/file name (document here) and instantiate `ResourceManager` accordingly as others mentioned.

Comment: Well, `properties.Resources` is of type `ResourceManager`, right? So just call `properties.Resources.GetStream(document)` - or `GetString` or `GetObject`, depending on what kind of resource you're working with.

Comment: @PieterWitvoet Thank you for your time.
But it isnt working. Also the so called duplicate isnt helping.
The resources are plain word documents and they are of type byte[] when i look in the recources of the solution.
Maybe my question isnt clear, but i just want to use a variable in Properties.Resources.StringVariable where StringVariable is a variable that i can assing a value before execution...

Comment: What do you mean with 'it isn't working'?

Comment: @PieterWitvoet I added the methode extractFile. I forgot to add it. Mybe it helps to have  a clear view on the problem...

Comment: So what exactly isn't working? What errors do you get? We're not psychic here... ;)

Comment: Just a sec, i'll get back to this. thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can get the resource by name like this:

```
string[] documents = new string[] { "one", "two", "three"};
foreach (var document in documents)
{
    var unmanagedMemoryStream = Resources.ResourceManager.GetStream(document);

    var memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
    unmanagedMemoryStream.CopyTo(memoryStream);
    memoryStream.Position = 0;
    byte[] bytes = memoryStream.ToArray();

    extractFile(String.Format(@"C:\temp\{0}.doc", document),
                bytes);
}
```

There are several methods available on `ResourceManager` that might be better suited depending on the type of the resource: `GetStream`, `GetString` or `GetObject`.

Comment: i get the error that properties recources doesnt contain definition for getstream...

Comment: Cannot convert from 'System.IO.UnmanagedMemoryStream' to 'byte[]'

Answer (score 0):

As a solution to the problem i zipped all needed files and added this 1 file to the resources.
I extracted it to temp folder and unzipped it to the appropriate locations as needed...